# How to classify docker container logs by container name using Fluent-bit?

Tags: docker, logging, lua, fluent-bit

We are using Fluent-bit to process our docker container logs, I can use Tail to specify container log path, but there are multiple different containers in that log path `/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log`. The first '*' can be interpreted to many different container_ids.

How can I acquire these ids?
If I could acquire these ids, how can I map them to docker container names? I want to use the container name to apply different filters to different container logs?

Comment: I was going to answer with the linked information but it doesn't answer your question. It's an alternative method.

https://betterstack.com/community/guides/logging/fluent-bit-explained/#collecting-logs-from-docker-containers-and-centralizing-logs

Answer (score 2):

You can use lua scripts to achieve this. container_name can be retrieved from the container's config file the same folder with the log file.

A sample configuration would be:

```
[INPUT]
  name tail
  Path /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log
  Path_Key filepath
  Parser json
  Skip_Empty_Lines true
  Tag container_logs
  Docker_Mode true
  Read_from_Head true

# Filter that uses lua scripts to extract container_id from file name and add it as an new field to log
[FILTER]
  Name lua
  Match container_logs
  script read_container_id_and_name.lua
  call get_container_id

# Filter that uses lua scripts to read container's config file and extract container_name then add it as a new field to log
[FILTER]
  Name lua
  Match container_logs
  script read_container_id_and_name.lua
  call get_container_name

# now you can classify your container logs by container_name using rewrite_tag
# Filter that change the tag based on logs' container_name
[FILTER]
  Name          rewrite_tag
  Match         container_logs
  Rule          $container_name ^container_name_a$ a_logs false
  Rule          $container_name ^container_name_b$ b_logs false
  Rule          $container_name ^container_name_c$ c_logs false
  Emitter_Name  re_emitted


# now you can use filters to different tags, like for a_logs tag
[FILTER]
  Name parser
  Match a_logs
  Key_Name log
  Parser a_logs_parser
  # Reserve all the fields except log.
  Reserve_Data On
```

The lua scripts can be like this:

```
-- read container_id from filepath field and add it as a new field
function get_container_id(tag, timestamp, record)
  path = record["filepath"]
  -- s = "./var/lib/docker/containers/a3118c5d7ff06b70100f0aee279b4811804453971bebad127a689e5cc5c8d7d8/a3118c5d7ff06b70100f0aee279b4811804453971bebad127a689e5cc5c8d7d8-json.log"
  container = {}
  for s in string.gmatch(path, "([^/]*)/") do
    table.insert(container, s)
  end
  record["container_id"] = container[6]
  return 2, timestamp, record
end

-- extract container_name from container's config file by regex and add it as a new field
-- this if useful for us to apply different filters to different container logs
function get_container_name(tag, timestamp, record)
  id = record["container_id"]
  file = "./var/lib/docker/containers/" .. id .. "/config.v2.json"
  if not file_exists(file) then return {} end
  local lines = ""
  for line in io.lines(file) do
    lines = lines .. line
  end

  pattern="\"LogPath\":\"[^\"]*\",\"Name\":\"[/]?([^\"]+)\""
  record["container_name"] = string.match(lines, pattern)
  return 2, timestamp, record
end

-- tell if a file exists on file system
function file_exists(file)
  local f = io.open(file, "rb")
  if f then f:close() end
  return f ~= nil
end
```

Note that this essentially apply IO and regex to each log entry Fluent-bit processed, it might cause performance impact. You might need to find the mapping before Fluent-bit start and pass it as env var to Fluent-bit